# Polymer 1.0 paper-dialog shows extremely compressed

Tags: modal-dialog, polymer-1.0

I can't seem to get the paper-dialog to show up correctly all of the time. It will show correctly once then it will show up compressed the next time when I click on it to the point that it looks like a line. Unfortunately, I am unable to add a picture of it since this is my first question.

I have removed my styling sheets from this element but could the other styling sheets of my other element be causing this problem? Any direction of what I should look at would be really helpful.
I setup this paper dialog with the following:

```
<paper-dialog id='addressDialog'
              opened="{{addressDialogOpened}}"
              no-cancel-on-outside-click
              no-cancel-on-esc-key
              entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation"
              exit-animation="scale-down-animation">
<div>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{newAddressDialog}}">
    <h2>Add an Address</h2>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{editAddressDialog}}">
    <h2>Edit Address Information</h2>
  </template>
  <hr>
</div>
```

It has a series of template repeats in it as well. I was reading about the paper dialog and it says that it has space for a header, content area, and buttons. Do I always have to set it up this way in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way that I saw to fix this terrible problem was to use a style of "min-height" and some percentage of the page. After I included this in my paper-dialog elements the popups were showing perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Additional solution is to add `position: fixed;` into your paper-dialog style like: 
`:host paper-dialog {  position: fixed; }`

Comment: I found that the default `paper-dialog` position wasn't being set to `fixed` until the entry animation was over, so it ended up doing all sorts of weird things to the element, as well as the rest of the page. Setting it to `position: fixed` in the CSS up front like you said fixed the problem for me.